# How to update android GPS regularly on the screen?

Tags: android

I am trying to measure how much I travel when the start button is clicked and stop measuring after I click stop button. To do that
(1) I have already set up location manager, location listen and location object and they are already working well before I put onClick Listener.
(2) After I set up onClickListener, GPS is not update regularly anymore. Is anyone know how to make GPS regularly update after event trigger? Following is my code.

```
public class MeasureDistance extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    TextView showData;
    Button start;
    Button stop;
    double longitutde;
    double previousLongitude;
    Location previous;
    Location current;
    LocationListener myListener;
    Location location;
    Location previousLocation = null;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    static double meter = 0;
    double distance = 0;
    boolean startGPS = false;
    double diff;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   //This is for the UI
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        showData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showText);
        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        //This is for the Location
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        if((previousLocation != location) && (previousLocation != null) &&(startGPS == true))
        {
            distance = location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
            meter = distance + meter;
        }
        previousLocation = location;
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    public View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(final View v){
            switch(v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.startButton:
                {
                    startGPS = true;
                    showData.setText(Double.toString(meter * 3.28));
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.stopButton:
                {
                    showData.setText("Stop Button is Click");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } ;
}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your problem; but you should usually turn the GPS in onStart() or onResume(), and turning it off in onPause() or onStop(). Turning it on in onCreate() will cause it to be running all the time, killing your battery.

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you want to implement is : 1) User presses Start and the location starts getting updated using the gps. 2) The distance continues to be updated as long as the user doesn't press the Stop 3) On Stop the location and distance is not updated anymore.

For 1) : You should register the location listener in the onClick() method of the Start Button. Currently you are registering the location listener in the onCreate(). Thus pressing the Start button will do nothing (except to display the distance in showData textview).

For 2) : Let the distance calculation be in the onLocationChanged() method. You should shift your display code, i.e, setting up the distance in showData textview to onLocationChanged() method. Currently your code updates the showData text with the calculated distance only on Start button click.

For 3) : On Stop button onClick() method you should unregister the location listener so that you don't request the location updates (when the user wants to stop).

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

Comment: Thank you, that exactly what I want to do. However, I am beginner on Android. Can you please explain me how to register Location Listener on OnClick? Because when I move location listener from onCreate to onClick, it give me error with "requestLocationUpdate"  here is my code.

Comment: move the locationManager.requestLocationUpdates() from onCreate to onClick of Start Button

Comment: public void onClick(final View v){
        switch(v.getId())
           {
            case R.id.startButton:
                 {
                    startGPS = true;
                   //This is for the Location
locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);                           location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);                           locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this);
showData.setText(Double.toString(meter * 3.28));  break; }